# If char is one byte how is this not undefined behavior

Tags: c, char, int, undefined-behavior

So an int is four bytes, I just don't understand how C knows to make this work in this case here

Random function to show what I mean

```
char strl[20];
int c, i=0;
puts("Enter a string up to 19 characters");
while((i<20) && (c=getChar())!="\n")
    strl[i++]=c;
```

Comment: C11 draft standard, `6.5.16.1 Simple assignment, Section 2 In simple assignment (=), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.` `6.5.16 Assignment operators, Section 3 An
assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment[...]`.

Comment: Ah, copy-pasted the wrong sentence in the second quote: `[...]The type of an assignment expression is the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion.`

Comment: I think it's undefined if it reaches EOF before reading a newline, because EOF is not a valid `char` value.

Comment: @EOF Given your handle, can you confirm that?

Comment: EOF is a macro and has value of -1 in *NIX world

Comment: @Barmar No. `EOF` has the value `-1` which is converted into either -1 if `char` is signed or `CHAR_MAX` (usually 255) if `char` is unsigned.

Comment: @GRC The standard specifies that `EOF` has the value -1.

Comment: @FUZxxl thank you, I was not sure of that but thank you for confirming.

Comment: Strip out the 3 unused bytes from an ASCII character held in an `int` (which will always take up one byte only), and you don't lose anything. So it could be held in a `long long` too and things would be fine in this case.

Comment: @FUZxxl: what standard specifies that? The C11 standard just says "a negative value" (7.21.1/3)

Comment: @rici Ah yes, that's POSIX, my bad. I was for some reason really sure that C11 would specify `EOF` to be -1, too.

Comment: All that arguing over EOF, and nobody noticed that it's comparing an `int` with `char *` .....

Answer (score 3):

C isn't a strongly typed language, and implicit conversions like this are common.

This example from the [C11 draft standard 6.5.16.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1p4) is very similar to yours:

```
int f(void);
char c;
/* ... */
if ((c = f()) == -1)
       /* ... */
```

> the int value returned by the function may be truncated when stored in
>   the char, and then converted back to int width prior to the
>   comparison.

So this behavior is well defined.

Edit: I realize that the above may not be the best example as the conversion from `int` to `char` will be defined by the implementation (if `char` defaults to `unsigned` or `signed`). However, it still demonstrates that this is *defined* behavior, and not undefined.

Comment: this was I believe defined in 89 as well, K&R ANCI C mentions says it as well.

Comment: @GRC I'm sure it was. I just wanted to quote the latest standard.

Comment: @GRC it's been part of C basically forever, since it ran on PDP11s.

Comment: I believe that the example you quote is intended to illustrate _incorrect_ code. The last sentence reads "Therefore, for full portability, the variable `c` should be declared as `int`."

Comment: @rici You're right. It's not portable code, which you might call malformed. But it still demonstrates that this is defined and not undefined behavior as in the question. I'll edit the answer with that disclaimer.